# unable to remove white space in html

Tags: php, whitespace, str-replace, trim, phpquery

I'm using phpQuery to fetch string from given url. as you can see in the image, there is a three space at the end of string appears like `&nbsp;` in chrome developer tools. i've used trim, `str_replace("&nbsp;","...")` and tried to convert unicode then remove it. but no luck.

[image]

```
 foreach(pq("div.index-title") as $sol_frame_basliklar){
    $baslik_text = pq($sol_frame_basliklar)->contents()->eq(0)->html();
    $baslik_entry_sayisi = pq($sol_frame_basliklar)->contents()->eq(1)->text();
    $baslik_text = trim($baslik_text, "\xC2\xA0\n" );
    echo '<tr   >
    <td valign="top">&middot;&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="192" class="li" ><div class="sol_list_div"><a href="#" target="sportakisim" class="liste"  title="('.$baslik_entry_sayisi.')" >'.$baslik_text.'</a>&nbsp;';
    if($baslik_entry_sayisi>0)
    echo '('.$baslik_entry_sayisi.')</div></td>';
  '</tr>';
  }
```

Comment: updated post with the last tried way

Comment: Can you give the raw result, without the developper tools view ?

Comment: yes it appears like this http://i.imgur.com/3hq9VbT.png
page i'm fetching strings is http://www.incisozluk.com.tr/enson/

Comment: str_replace('&nbsp;','',$var); where $var is yours variable - try it like that - maybe spacebar is already encoded then trim will not work.

Comment: i tried that already, no luck

Comment: It looks like the visible spaces are due to the `&nbsp;` part that you add after the `</a>` closing tag. When I ask the raw code, it's what you obtain when pressing `CTRL + U`.

Comment: sorry here you go
http://pastebin.com/KcLmUCUr

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$baslik_text = trim($baslik_text, "\xC2\xA0\n" );
```

With

```
$baslik_text = trim($baslik_text);
```

`\xC2\xA0` is the unicode value for non-breaking space. So, if it's a simple space (`\x20`) it will not match. See [PHP: trim - Manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php) for more information about the function.

Comment: i have tried that one before, thanks anyway i have solved it by
`str_replace("&nbsp;","",htmlentities(trim($baslik_text), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));`